# How can I perform an analysis of the NHIS imputed income variables?

Tags: dataset, stata, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have downloaded five family income variables from https://nhis.ipums.org/nhis-action/variables/group?id=economic_income (INCPPOINT1, INCPPOINT2, INCPPOINT3, INCPPOINT4, INCPPOINT5) for they years going from 2009 to 2018.

These variables come as imputed point estimates.

My question now is: how can I use these imputed incomes to include them in a futher regression to study the relation between health status and income via DiD?

I do not know if it possible but I would be willing to turn these variables into a single one and then use this new variable for my purpose. Basically, I need the income variable in order to know if individuals are treated or not. If possible, how can I do it in Stata?

Of course I can also use other softwares but I'm working on Stata right now and I'm not very familiar with any other tool at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Stata has pretty good facilities for handling multiply imputed data. Look at `-mi set-` and `-mi register-`to set up the data and `-mi estimate-` to run models.

Comment: I checked on the Stata help and found that mi command does not support Difference in Differences/TWFE estimation. Does anyone have a clue about how I can deal with imputed income variables in this setting? The income variable I would like to obtain will be both useful to divide treated and controls and also to be included in the regression